# Change margin-top as user scrolls

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to get a div to scroll up at the same amount of pixels as the user scrolls down the page. For example, in Google Chrome when using the mouse wheel, it scrolls down in about 20px intervals. But when you scroll down using the handle, the scrolling amount varies.

Here is my code so far:

```
var scrollCtr = 50;
$(window).scroll(function(){
   scrollCtr = scrollCtr - 20;
   $('div.nexus-files').css('margin-top', scrollCtr + 'px');
});
```

There are a few problems with this:

1. The user scrolling varies
2. It needs to subtract from margin-top if scrolling down and add to margin-top if scrolling up

Here is an example:
http://www.enflick.com/

Thanks for the help

Comment: How about CSS, `position: fixed`? What's this for?

Comment: Here is what I am trying to do: http://www.enflick.com/

Comment: see my answer below - about the `position:fixed` solution - and learn how to use firebug/Chrome developer tools - it could have save you the effort of asking this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally Got it

Here is the code I used to accomplish the task.

Most of the code is from http://enflick.com and I modified it to work with my individual situation.

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){
initParallax();
});

// parallax init
function initParallax(){
var win = jQuery(window);
var wrapper = jQuery('#wrapper');
var bg1 = wrapper.find('.nexus-files');
var koeff = 0.55;
if (bg1.length) {
    function refreshPosition(){
        var scrolled = win.scrollTop();
        var maxOffsetY1 = 450;
        var offsetY1 = scrolled * koeff;
        var offsetY2 = scrolled * koeff - (maxOffsetY1 * koeff - offsetY1);
        if (offsetY1 <= maxOffsetY1 * koeff - offsetY1) {
            bg1.css("margin-top", +-offsetY1+"px");
            //alert(+-offsetY1+"px");
        }
    }
    refreshPosition();
    win.bind('resize scroll', refreshPosition);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're doing it the wrong way, what you are trying to do should be done using `position: fixed` on `div.nexus-files`

```
div.nexus-files{position: fixed; top: 0;}
```

but anyway - if you still want to know what you can do with the scroll event - you better get to `scrollTop` of the document and set the `margin-top` to the same value

```
window.onscroll = function(event){
    var doc = document.documentElement, body = document.body;
    var top = (doc && doc.scrollTop  || body && body.scrollTop  || 0);
    document.getElementById('nexus-files_id').style.marginTop = top+'px';
}
```

I'm using pure Javascript instead of jQuery because of the overhead that might be crucial when the browser need to calculate stuff in a very short amount of time (during the scrolling). [this can be done even more efficient by storing reference to the element and the doc... but you know..)

I used id based selector to get the specific element instead of class based

AND I SAY AGAIN - this is not how you should do what you were trying to do

Comment: And if not this, you realize you can access the current scrollTop of the window or other elements inside the handler.  You don't need to start with a static number and guess.

Comment: I am trying to reverse the margin to go in the opposite direction. Here is what I am trying to do: http://enflick.com

Comment: the direction doesn't matter! when you use the `scrollTop` property you get the current scroll position after scrolling - whether it was up or down
and still - you really shouldn't do it with javascript! 
look at line no. 89 in the css file of the reference you gave: http://www.enflick.com/wp-content/themes/enflick/all.css

Comment: How would I make it reverse if using fixed? `position: fixed;` moves with the scrolling not the opposite direction?

Comment: one of us doesn't understand the other - and because I can't understand the point you are trying to make with the "opposite direction" - I will stick to the reference you gave - 
this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/FNnNX/ has an example of how you should do it with `position: fixed`

Comment: Noooo im not talking about the entire page. I mean just the phones. Look at the phones, they move separate from the page to reveal more of the phone as you scroll.

Comment: OK, now I understand - but still, the direction doesn't matter... you need to create a function the gets the current `scrollTop` and returns the current `margin-top` (in the reference the movement is done using `background-position`. I don't know what you are trying to do exactly - but `margin` is probably not the right property to change)

Answer (score 1):

Why not using the actual scroll offset as reference or position ?

```
// or whatever offset you need
var scrollOffset = document.body.scrollTop + 20;

// jQuery
var scrollOffset = $("body").scrollTop() + 20;
```